# Play 2.1-RC1 reverse routing not compiling

Tags: scala, playframework-2.1

Updated to play 2.1-RC1 and seem to have problems with reverse routing
In

```
routes.ControlPanel.CPanel.index
```

**Compile error**: value ControlPanel is not a member of object controllers.ControlPanel.routes

Also importing produces a warning

```
import controllers.routes
```

imported `routes' is permanently hidden by definition of object routes in package ControlPanel

Everything works fine with 2.0.4 . My controller stucture is like so:

```
 -- app  
    -- controllers
        -- ControlPanel
            --CPanel.scala
```

Can't find anything at [Migration Guide](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/wiki/Migration)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ControlPanel.routes.CPanel.index
```

solves it